# Count null or non null values for every column in a table

Tags: sql, sql-server, count, null

I need help with coding counter for null/non null values for all tables in a table. I know how to do it with one column but don't know how to incorporate it with all columns.

IN EXAMPLE

```
              CITY         STATE       CONTINENT
MICHAEL.E     NULL         NY          NA
JOHN.D        PARIS        FR          EU
NICOLAS.B     FRANKFURT    GE          EU
MING.Y        NULL         NULL        AF
```

So I would get results like

```
column      null       not_null ....
city        2          2
state       1          3
continent   0          4
```

I am certain that it has to be used with list of all column IDs that can be get from

```
SELECT DISTINCT AC.object_id, AC.name, AC.column_id 
     FROM SYS.all_columns AC JOIN sys.all_objects AO 
       ON AC.object_id=AO.object_id 
      WHERE AO.name='MY_TABLE_NAME'
```

And since i have many tables to deal with and many of them have 600+ columns
 I would need solution for that application.

Comment: Is this for one table, or will you be using it on multiple tables? Also, which DBMS?

Answer (score 1):

I would use `APPLY` :

```
select cols as [column], 
       sum(case when col is null then 1 else 0 end) as [null],
       sum(case when col is not null then 1 else 0 end) as [not_null]
from table t cross apply
     ( values ('city', city), 
              ('state', state), 
              ('continent', continent),
              . . .
     ) tt (cols, col)
group by cols;
```

**EDIT** :

```
select cols, 
       sum(case when col is null then 1 else 0 end) as Null_value, 
       sum(case when col is not null then 1 else 0 end) as not_null_value 
from TABLE_NAME cross apply 
     ( values ('Column_1', Column_1), 
              ('Column_2', Column_2), 
              ('Column_3', Column_3), 
              ('Column_4', Column_4), 
              ('Column_5', Column_5)   
     ) tt (cols,col) 
group by cols;
```

Comment: I tried your solution and got error near  ",", But only because i putted another "(" after values and at the end of array of columns, columns' values.

Comment: @sebekkg. . . There is no array. Use just add more columns.

Comment: if i use in same way without "(" after value and ")" after last one like in:
select cols, 
       sum(case when col is null then 1 else 0 end) as Null_value,
       sum(case when col is not null then 1 else 0 end) as not_null_value
from  TABLE_NAME cross apply
      (  values
     ('Column_1',Column_1),
  ('Column_2', Column_2),
  ('Column_3, Column_3)
 ) tt (cols,col)
group by cols

I get error "Operand type clash: uniqueidentifier is incompatible with datetime". 

And if i use () i get error IN syntax near "," after 'Column_1',

Comment: @sebekkg. . . `Column_3` has end_close is missing.

Comment: I don't understand.

Answer (score 0):

SQL Server and Oracle

```
with CTE as
(
  select ColName, ColVal
  from 
  (
    select name, city, state, continent
    from mytable
  ) t1
    unpivot
  (
    ColVal for ColName in (city, state, continent)
  )
)
select ColName,
       sum(case when ColVal is null then 1 else 0 end) as nulls,
       sum(case when ColVal is null then 0 else 1 end) as not_nulls
from CTE
```

Comment: In this case should i incorporate my code in T1 part? or in 

ColVal for ColName in (SELECT DISTINCT AC.name FROM SYS.all_columns AC JOIN sys.all_objects AO ON AC.object_id=AO.object_id WHERE AO.name='MY_TABLE')

Comment: @sebekkg No. That will not work. If you need to do this for mnore than one table, you will need to write a TSQL procedure to execute dynamically. If it's just for this table, lose the code you wrote.

Comment: My problem is that table that i need to use it for contains 1016 columns and i have many tables like that. So I should first extract list of fields then put it in this T1 select? 

What is deal with procedure? Is that more complicated approach?